# Is it possible to multiplex the same frequency (without bandwidth division)?

Tags: rf, multiplexer, rfid

I have a range of bandwidth (e.g. `[865,868] MHz`) and more than one RFID tag I'd like to receive information from, over that range.

How could I multiplex those frequencies among those tags? Is that possible?

If so, what is the maximum number of tags I can interact with?

Communication is not needed to happen in real time; indeed, even a latency of order of minutes is good.

Comment: Yes. Ready for some reading? http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/papers/Multi_Tags_Journal.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In short, if you use modulation in the returned signal from your RFID tags, then a resolution time of even several seconds can allow for billions of different tag-codes to be used.

In the end, it just comes down to how sophisticated you can afford to make your components before buying more bandwidth from the FCC becomes more cost-conscious.

Comment: This is too short on details to be an answer - at present it is basically a comment.

Comment: @ChrisStratton well, I could respondmwith a 48-pzge book listing all of the optkons, but this is the best direct answer that can be given on such a broad question. Out of curiosity, why would you dig up a month-old post just to degrade the only posted answer?